# Eclipse RCP: Add required plugins automatically to feature

Tags: plugins, dependencies, rcp

I find that Run Configurations has a "powerful" button on the "Plug-ins" tab. It's the "Add Required Plugins" button. When I deselect all, and then tick on my plugins on Workspace, and click this button, it helps me to include a good dependencies (minimum, required plugins) list, ready to run (validate successfully).

Now I have a product, feature-based. I already add my plugins to that feature. But it's not able to run (missing constraint, etc.)
How can I add dependencies to my feature in the "Plug-ins and Fragments" editor? Because when I click "Synchronize" in the .product file, a new collection of dependencies is generated based on my feature.xml which usually doesn't have enough plugins to run. It's very hard to add one-by-one, if we have a screencapture of the minimum, required plugins list as I said above.

Button "Add required" on Dependencies tab of .product file is not helpful in this case.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse offers to initialize a feature using a given launch configuration. (The dialog after File-New.. -Feature)

You could create a new feature,
choose the launch-configuration, 
open the resulting 'feature.xml' as text (Context menu/Open with), 
copy the contents of the require section into your old feature, 
delete the new Feature again.

(There has to be a better/more proper way to do this)